# Pandas column fillna from a function with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to store an api response into a pandas column where values are `np.nan` with a condition. Store function return / api response where rows are in the `mlst` and `c` is np.nan.

I tried the following, but it doesn't store the response into the `a` column.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# mock dict
d = dict({'v1': 'xxx1', 'v2': 'xxx2'})

def api_res(val):

    # make api call
    res = d.get(val)

    return res

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'm': ['M1','M2','M3'],
                   'v': ['v1','v2','v3'],
                   'c': [np.nan, 1, np.nan],
                   'a': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
                 })

mlst = ['M1','M2']

df[(df['m'].isin(mlst)) & (df['c'].isna())]['a'].fillna(df.apply(lambda x: api_res(x['v']), axis=1), inplace=True)
```

Expected output:

```
a 

xxx1
np.nan
np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises from the [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy). You are indexing `df` twice, so you are in fact filling in-place the NaNs of a different DataFrame object, not of the original `df`. Therefore the original `df` remains the same.

Try this

```
mask = df['m'].isin(mlst) & df['c'].isna()

df.loc[mask, 'a'] = df.loc[mask, 'a'].fillna(df.loc[mask, 'v'].apply(api_res))
```

Output:

```
>>> df

    m   v    c     a
0  M1  v1  NaN  xxx1
1  M2  v2  1.0   NaN
2  M3  v3  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use `.apply` with `lambda`. can you suggest a solution with that approach?

Comment: You can replace `api_res` with `lambda x: api_res(x)`. It's the same thing.

Comment: @kms why, may I ask? In the real scenario, do you want to pass other arguments to the function?

Comment: @Rodalm yes, there are other args.

Comment: Are they args from the dataframe, or static args?

Comment: @kms then just use Nick's suggestion, just change `.apply(api_res)` to `.apply(lambda x: api_res(x, arg1=..., arg2=..., etc))`

Comment: @BeRT2me from the dataframe. so `x['col1']` ....

Comment: @kms In that case, since you just want to pass other columns, you can just use `df[mask].apply(api_res, axis=1)` and redefine the signature of your function to `def api_response(row)`, and inside the function use the row fields you like by indexing them, i.e. `col1 = row['col1']`, etc. Another alternative is using  `df[mask].apply(lambda row: api_res(row['v'], row['col1']), axis=1)`

Comment: @kms I updated my answer to show `apply` with a DataFrame instead of a Series~

Comment: @BeRT2me @Rodalm could add a bit of explanation on how `mask` works?

Comment: @kms There is nothing special about `mask`, it's just a variable, which is a boolean Series resulting from the conditions `df['m'].isin(mlst) & df['c'].isna()`. It's the same of using the conditions directly inside the brackets without defining the variable, as you do. I'm just saving that value to a variable and use it in the next line to simply the code and make it more readable and less exhaustive

Comment: @kms `df.loc[mask, col]`selects the column `col` of the rows which satisfy the condition `mask`, i.e. their corresponding  value in `mask` is True

Answer (score 1):

```
def api_res(v, m):
    return d.get(v) + m

mlst = ['M1','M2']

mask = df.m.isin(mlst) & df.c.isna()
df.loc[mask, 'a'] = df[mask].apply(lambda x: api_res(x.v, x.m), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    m   v    c       a
0  M1  v1  NaN  xxx1M1
1  M2  v2  1.0     NaN
2  M3  v3  NaN     NaN
```

---

If you explicitly want `fillna` like functionality, that can be achieved by just be adding one more requirement to the mask:

```
mask = df.m.isin(mlst) & df.c.isna() & df.a.isna()
df.loc[mask, 'a'] = df[mask].apply(lambda x: api_res(x.v, x.m), axis=1)
```